# Calculation difference between matlab and python

Tags: python, matlab, matrix

I want to ask about the strange calculation value of the following code.

Below is the Python code.

```
import torch

A = torch.tensor(
    [3.3800, -19.6800, 0.6068, 7.0446, 7.7432, 1.1609, 6.8291, 18.1406, 1.0961, 9.6257, 37.1004, 2.2859, 12.2999,
     49.8486, 0.8633, 12.1398, 55.5434, 0.6883, 17.7870, 36.8969, -14.0621, 18.6520, 41.6817, -30.3517, -14.7453,
     45.3222, -27.6966, -17.8465, 66.2168, 2.1292, 7.1283, 36.3618, 20.3197, -3.9434, 39.3879, 32.8596, -33.9162,
     41.0636, 17.5462, -43.9130, 60.8502, -11.5111, 5.1221, -19.6117, -14.2915, 6.0492, -78.7564, -22.6186, -0.9958,
     -159.6541, -34.1748, 1.6379, -19.7480, 15.5055, 5.0580, -78.7725, 24.0265, 2.6067, -159.9346, 35.6184])
A = torch.reshape(A, (1, 60))

B = torch.tensor(
    [3.3800, -19.6800, 0.6068, 7.0446, 7.7432, 1.1609, 6.8291, 18.1406, 1.0961, 9.6257, 37.1004, 2.2859, 12.2999,
     49.8486, 0.8633, 12.1398, 55.5434, 0.6883, 17.7870, 36.8969, -14.0621, 18.6520, 41.6817, -30.3517, -14.7453,
     45.3222, -27.6966, -17.8465, 66.2168, 2.1292, 7.1283, 36.3618, 20.3197, -3.9434, 39.3879, 32.8596, -33.9162,
     41.0636, 17.5462, -43.9130, 60.8502, -11.5111, 5.1221, -19.6117, -14.2915, 6.0492, -78.7564, -22.6186, -0.9958,
     -159.6541, -34.1748, 1.6379, -19.7480, 15.5055, 5.0580, -78.7725, 24.0265, 2.6067, -159.9346, 35.6184])
B = torch.reshape(B, (60, 1))

C = torch.tensor(
    [3.3800, -19.6799, 0.6082, 7.0446, 7.7431, 1.1623,
     6.8292, 18.1407, 1.0974, 9.6257, 37.1004, 2.2595,
     12.2998, 49.8486, 0.8661, 12.1398, 55.5437, 0.6901,
     17.7871, 36.8968, -14.0608, 18.6520, 41.6817, -30.3506,
     -14.7454, 45.3224, -27.6954, -17.8464, 66.2163, 2.1305,
     7.1283, 36.3618, 20.3210, -3.9434, 39.3880, 32.8612,
     -33.9162, 41.0638, 17.5475, -43.9131, 60.8501, -11.5098,
     5.1221, -19.6117, -14.2901, 6.0491, -78.7549, -22.6173,
     -0.9958, -159.6550, -34.1736, 1.6379, -19.7481, 15.5065,
     5.0580, -78.7719, 24.0277, 2.6067, -159.9361, 35.6196])
C = torch.reshape(C, (1, 60))

D = torch.tensor(
    [3.38, -19.6799, 0.6082, 7.0446, 7.7431, 1.1623, 6.8292, 18.1407, 1.0974, 9.6257, 37.1004, 2.2595, 12.2998, 49.8486,
     0.8661, 12.1398, 55.5437, 0.6901, 17.7871, 36.8968, -14.0608, 18.652, 41.6817, -30.3506, -14.7454, 45.3224,
     -27.6954, -17.8464, 66.2163, 2.1305, 7.1283, 36.3618, 20.321, -3.9434, 39.388, 32.8612, -33.9162, 41.0638, 17.5475,
     -43.9131, 60.8501, -11.5098, 5.1221, -19.6117, -14.2901, 6.0491, -78.7549, -22.6173, -0.9958, -159.655, -34.1736,
     1.6379, -19.7481, 15.5065, 5.058, -78.7719, 24.0277, 2.6067, -159.9361, 35.6196])
D = torch.reshape(D, (60, 1))

First_term = torch.mm(A,B)
Second_term = torch.mm(C,B)
Third_term = torch.mm(C,D)

ans = (First_term / 2) - Second_term + (Third_term / 2)

print(torch.sum(A.T-B))
print(torch.sum(C.T-D))
print(ans)
```

Below is the code composed in matlab.

```
A = [3.3800, -19.6800, 0.6068, 7.0446, 7.7432, 1.1609, 6.8291, 18.1406, 1.0961, 9.6257, 37.1004, 2.2859, 12.2999,49.8486, 0.8633, 12.1398, 55.5434, 0.6883, 17.7870, 36.8969, -14.0621, 18.6520, 41.6817, -30.3517, -14.7453,45.3222, -27.6966, -17.8465, 66.2168, 2.1292, 7.1283, 36.3618, 20.3197, -3.9434, 39.3879, 32.8596, -33.9162,41.0636, 17.5462, -43.9130, 60.8502, -11.5111, 5.1221, -19.6117, -14.2915, 6.0492, -78.7564, -22.6186, -0.9958,-159.6541, -34.1748, 1.6379, -19.7480, 15.5055, 5.0580, -78.7725, 24.0265, 2.6067, -159.9346, 35.6184]
B = A'
C = [3.3800, -19.6799, 0.6082, 7.0446, 7.7431, 1.1623,6.8292, 18.1407, 1.0974, 9.6257, 37.1004, 2.2595,12.2998, 49.8486, 0.8661, 12.1398, 55.5437, 0.6901,17.7871, 36.8968, -14.0608, 18.6520, 41.6817, -30.3506,-14.7454, 45.3224, -27.6954, -17.8464, 66.2163, 2.1305,7.1283, 36.3618, 20.3210, -3.9434, 39.3880, 32.8612,-33.9162, 41.0638, 17.5475, -43.9131, 60.8501, -11.5098,5.1221, -19.6117, -14.2901, 6.0491, -78.7549, -22.6173,-0.9958, -159.6550, -34.1736, 1.6379, -19.7481, 15.5065,5.0580, -78.7719, 24.0277, 2.6067, -159.9361, 35.6196]
D = C'

First_term = A*B
Second_term = C*B
Third_term = C*D

ans = (First_term / 2) - Second_term + (Third_term / 2)
```

Looking at the code above, the A matrix is equal to the transpose of B, and the C matrix is equal to the transpose of D. That is, the formula for ans is of the form "x^2 - 2xy+ y^2". But in the python file, negative values come out. When you look at the formula, it is judged that absolutely negative values cannot come out. When you check the above results in Matlab, you can see that positive values come out normally.

I would like to know what the difference is in this part.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to consider is how you transpose your matrices. While this does not affect your answer in this scenario, as you are transposing a 2D matrix with one of the dimensions being 1, it can be a factor if that is not the case.

```
a = torch.arange(6.)
b = torch.reshape(a, (3, 2))
c = torch.reshape(a, (2,3))

b:
tensor([[0., 1.],
        [2., 3.],
        [4., 5.]])

c:
tensor([[0., 1., 2.],
        [3., 4., 5.]])
```

You should be using the `transpose` or `t` method:

```
d = torch.transpose(b, 0, 1)
d:
tensor([[0., 2., 4.],
        [1., 3., 5.]])

e = torch.t(b)
e:
tensor([[0., 2., 4.],
        [1., 3., 5.]])
```

As you can see, using reshape (resulting in c) has a different result from transposing the matrix that you want to transpose. However, the error is likely from a precision error, as setting the dtype of the tensor to `float64` produces a result similar to the MatLab result, albeit still not to the same precision.

Full code:

```
import torch

A = torch.tensor([
    [3.3800, -19.6800, 0.6068, 7.0446, 7.7432, 1.1609, 6.8291, 18.1406, 1.0961, 9.6257, 37.1004, 2.2859, 12.2999,
     49.8486, 0.8633, 12.1398, 55.5434, 0.6883, 17.7870, 36.8969, -14.0621, 18.6520, 41.6817, -30.3517, -14.7453,
     45.3222, -27.6966, -17.8465, 66.2168, 2.1292, 7.1283, 36.3618, 20.3197, -3.9434, 39.3879, 32.8596, -33.9162,
     41.0636, 17.5462, -43.9130, 60.8502, -11.5111, 5.1221, -19.6117, -14.2915, 6.0492, -78.7564, -22.6186, -0.9958,
     -159.6541, -34.1748, 1.6379, -19.7480, 15.5055, 5.0580, -78.7725, 24.0265, 2.6067, -159.9346, 35.6184]], dtype=torch.float64)
A = torch.reshape(A, (1, 60))

B = torch.t(A)

C = torch.tensor(
    [[3.3800, -19.6799, 0.6082, 7.0446, 7.7431, 1.1623,
     6.8292, 18.1407, 1.0974, 9.6257, 37.1004, 2.2595,
     12.2998, 49.8486, 0.8661, 12.1398, 55.5437, 0.6901,
     17.7871, 36.8968, -14.0608, 18.6520, 41.6817, -30.3506,
     -14.7454, 45.3224, -27.6954, -17.8464, 66.2163, 2.1305,
     7.1283, 36.3618, 20.3210, -3.9434, 39.3880, 32.8612,
     -33.9162, 41.0638, 17.5475, -43.9131, 60.8501, -11.5098,
     5.1221, -19.6117, -14.2901, 6.0491, -78.7549, -22.6173,
     -0.9958, -159.6550, -34.1736, 1.6379, -19.7481, 15.5065,
     5.0580, -78.7719, 24.0277, 2.6067, -159.9361, 35.6196]], dtype=torch.float64)
C = torch.reshape(C, (1, 60))

D = torch.t(C)

First_term = torch.mm(A,B)
Second_term = torch.mm(C,B)
Third_term = torch.mm(C,D)

ans = (First_term / 2) - Second_term + (Third_term / 2)

print(torch.sum(A.T-B))
print(torch.sum(C.T-D))
print(ans)
```

Comment: As you said, torch.transpose was used, but it was confirmed that negative values were still output the same in the Python code.

Comment: which negative values are you referring to? I'm getting `tensor([[102519.8015]], dtype=torch.float64)`, 
`tensor([[102519.9690]], dtype=torch.float64)`, 
`tensor([[102520.1373]], dtype=torch.float64)` for first second and third term respectively. The `ans` is still different, with the python code giving a tensor of `0.0004` while MatLab gives me `3.7126e-04`. That might be a precision related issue though.

Comment: In my case ans value is -0.0039. first second third term is tensor([[102519.7969]])
Tensor([[102519.9688]])
I get tensor([[102520.1328]]) . Is it okay to look at the problem with this as a difference in precision? If you don't mind, can I get the code you used?

Comment: Edited in the answer

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem was that the data type was not set to float 64, so a problem occurred in precision.

Comment: @CrisLuengo That is true, I didn't consider that the original question was reshaping with one of the sides having a dimension of 1. I would still say that using the transpose functionality is safer as it ensures that the result is correct regardless of original dimension, but I will correct the statement in the answer.